# Angularjs some routes slow to load

Tags: angularjs, routes, route-provider

I am having a very bizarre situation that I can't seem to figure out.  Here are my routes:

```
$routeProvider.when(/application1/:type, {
          templateUrl: "application1/index.html"
        })
.when(/application1/:type/:folder, {
          templateUrl: "application1/index.html"
        })
.when(/application2, {
          templateUrl: "application2/index.html"
        })
.when(/application3, {
          templateUrl: "application3/index.html"
        });
```

For some reason when I use $location.path on application2 and application3 it works fine and updates right when i call it.  However anytime I switch to anything on application1 it takes about 3-5 seconds, then starts to load.  When I refresh the page on application1 it works right away so I don't think it is the code that is associated with it.  How can certain routes behave so differently?

UPDATE: I ran a profiler on my application: It seems to be take 5+ seconds to run $apply and/or $digest when loading a route in application1.  What can be ways for me to speed this process up?

Comment: If you comment out your entire controller for "application1" is it still slow? My gut feeling is this is something in your controller, an ng-repeat or something else in the view that is running really slowly. This is probably not a routing issue.

Comment: I have added a breakpoint to the very first line to of the first controller that is loaded.  This line is not hit until after the delay is over.  I also checked for the routeSuccessful event and that fires instantly.  There is the massive delay between the routeSuccessful event firing and the first line of the first loaded controller.

Comment: It was just a matter of the model being too massive on $apply and $digest.  Essentially I clear the model before a route change and that significantly boosted the speed.

Comment: How did you do it exactly? I got a similar problem that could benefit from the same solution.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem that routing worked when starting but becomes slow at doing specific routes. Since it worked when started i thought `$route.reload();` might do the trick.

```
$route.reload();
$location.path("application1/");
```

This fix worked for me. Don't ask me the detailed explanation though.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! "Don't ask me the detailed explanation" goes against the entire foundation of this site. That's literally exactly why we come here: for detailed explanations. So please edit this answer to include one.

Comment: @user155407 I think the man was saying he didn't know the detailed explanation. Neither do I, for the record.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue happen to me.  It turns out it was because my function that was calling `$location.url` was called from jQuery "`.on`" (jQLite actually).  I had forgotten about how with AngularJS if you are called from something outside the `$digest` cycle you need to call `$applyAsync` (or `$apply`) to do "AngularJS stuff".  Maybe if it wasn't for my timeout timer it would have not worked at all (I think when that kicked off that's when the new view finally was processed).

The fix in my case was to change this (this is CoffeeScript but same sort of deal in pure JavaScript):

```
element.on 'hidden.bs.modal', () ->
    stuffIncludingLocationUrlCall()
```

to this:

```
element.on 'hidden.bs.modal', () ->
    scope.$applyAsync ->
        stuffIncludingLocationUrlCall()
```

Now the view change from `$location.url` happens really fast.

---

**Edit:** Here's a Javascript & jQuery version for those that come across this, as I did...

```
$(element).on("click", function() {

    // any processing or other logic you need goes here

    $scope.apply(function() {
        $location.path("new/path");
    });
});
```